# Can I play Mass Effect 3 in First Person Mode?

Tags: mass-effect-3

It bugs me that my character covers part of the screen.

Can I play this game in First Person Mode or in a less annoying Third Person Mode? How?

Comment: I am making a mod for FPS! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUgfmj9cfHI

Comment: You can increase the field of view so you can see around your character better. I can post an answer for that if you'd like.

Comment: @Ampersand: Up to you, you'll get my vote if you do.

Comment: It'd end up being a copy-paste of either the wiki page http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_(Mass_Effect_3)#Editing_FOV or this answer http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54868/15241 However I will post a specific answer to "less annoying Third Person Mode".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tweaking the Field of View

1. Back up your Coalesced.bin and save files
   `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Origin Games\Mass Effect 3\BIOGame\CookedPCConsole\`
   `%Username%\My Documents\Bioware\Mass Effect 3\Save\`
2. [Download the coalesced editor.](http://wenchy.net/me3-coalesced-utility)
3. Run the editor, open Coalesced.bin
4. Navigate to
   `bioinput.ini > sfxgame > sfxgamemodebase > bindings (multiple)`
   Replace "Shared_Aim" line with
   `( Name="Shared_Aim", Command="SwapWeaponIfEmpty | TightAim | FOV 0 | OnRelease FOV 101 | OnRelease StopTightAim" )`
5. Navigate to
   `bioinput.ini > sfxgame > sfxgamemodecinematic > bindings (multiple)`
   Add a line
   `( Name="RightMouseButton", Command="FOV 0")`
6. Navigate to
   `bioinput.ini > sfxgame > sfxgamemodeconversation > bindings (multiple)`
   Add a line
   `( Name="RightMouseButton", Command="FOV 0")`
7. Save, then close the editor.

Step 4 makes it so when you aim down the sights you use the normal zoomed fov, but go to a wider 101 degrees when you release the aim key. Feel free to change the value to suit.
Steps 5 and 6 allow you to reset the fov to default when a conversation or cinematic starts by pressing the Right Mouse Button, so as to avoid seeing visual glitches that would otherwise be hidden.

Answer (score 8):

No, Mass Effect 3 is a third person shooter.  Except for situations where you're zooming with a scoped weapon, you're always going to be in third person.

When aiming down sights on other weapons, the camera pulls in slightly, but otherwise there's really very little in the way of camera controls.

Answer (score 4):

No. The Mass Effect series is, and has always been, strictly 3rd-person perspective, with no in-game support for adjusting graphic style or controls.

Mass Effect 3 is no different.

PC users get the short end of the stick, here.

Comment: very true, that is