# How can I edit coalesced.bin so that I can use cheats and graphics tweaks?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

I've seen that I can tweak my game by editing files like bioinput.ini and bioengine.ini, but I couldn't find these files anywhere. They seem to be part of another file called coalesced.bin, and I don't know how to edit it. I want to do this so that I can tweak some graphics settings and set up some cheats, like unlimited ammo, free skill points, free credits, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can I use it to unlock default femshep's hair?

Comment: Dynamite write up, well done.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A lot of game tweaks are possible for the PC version of Mass Effect 3, both in terms of graphics and "cheats", and can be done by editing Coalesced.bin. Most of the results you find when you Google for how to do a tweak or cheat will tell you which ini file and variable to change, but not exactly HOW to do that.

**Warning before you start:** I do not recommend using any "cheats" or a modified Coalesced.bin file if you are going to play multiplayer. You may end up banned. See [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54602/3062).

The coalesced.bin file is basically a collection of variables that the game uses to determine different things, from graphical effects to key bindings to things like shield recharge rates. You can affect the game in fairly signficant ways by modifying this file. To do so, you'll want to grab the ME3 Coalesced Utility.

### ME3 Coalesced Utility? What?

It's a tool that unpacks the .bin file so that you can edit it, and then repacks it when you save. There are many ways you can do this, but this is the easiest to use tool that I've found. [You can grab it here](http://wenchy.net/me3-coalesced-utility/).

### So where is coalesced.bin?

- Its in your Mass Effect 3 install directory, under \BIOGame\CookedPCConsole.

### Err... okay. Where's my Mass Effect 3 install directory?

- [I discuss how to find that here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54127/3062)

### Okay, I've got those. Now what?

1. Make a backup (i.e., copy and paste somewhere) of your Coalesced.bin file first. You'll want this as a backup in case something goes wrong, and also so you can swap back to it if you're going to play multiplayer.
2. Run the tool. Go to File->Open.
3. Select the Coalesced.bin file discussed above.

You should get a screen that looks like this:

[image]

### Okay, I'm ready! What settings can I tweak?

Way more than I'm going to go into. If you want to know if something specific is possible, either Google for it or post a question and ask.

One common usage will probably be to bind keys to commands so that you can manually trigger them in-game. For example, this is how the current answer about [how to tweak your Field of View](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54220/3062) does it. You smack a numpad key and it changes your FOV. In general, you can do a lot of things this way by doing the following:

- Go to *bioinput.ini->sfxgame->sfxgamemodebase->bindings*
- (see screenshot below) On the right hand side, scroll to the bottom and enter something that looks something like this: (Name = "NumPadZero", Command = "something")
- Obviously, you could use NumPadOne, NumPadTwo, or whatever you like.
- Replace "something" with the actual command you wish to execute.

[image]

Here are a few example commands:

- **fov 90** - As already mentioned, you could set the FOV to 90 (or any other number) this way
- **initcredits 9999999** - will set your credits to 9999999
- **initammo 999** - give yourself a bunch of ammo
- **God** - turn on god mode (though instant-kill attacks can still kill you)

[This page lists even more commands.](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_%28Mass_Effect_3%29)

Again, this is about *how* to edit the file, not necessarily *what* to edit. If there's something you want, like how to unlock all weapons (which you can do), Google it and and you'll probably quickly find the command you need. Or ask a specific question about what you want to do (via the "Ask a Question" button up top, **not** by leaving a comment on this answer). I'm not trying to turn this answer into a repository for every possible cheat and tweak. The purpose was to explain to you how you get to the point where you enter these commands in the first place.

### Can I use this with multiplayer?

*I do not recommend you use this with multiplayer!* Yes, I said this already. It was worth saying twice. [I have seen rumors](http://social.bioware.com/forums/forum/1/topic/323/index/9692874/1) that EA might block/ban players who are using a tweaked file, since they could use it to cheat. [I'm trying to get a definite answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54602/3062) on if non-cheating tweaks will be a problem, but for now, better safe than sorry.

Comment: Very nice man! the only thing is that made me sick and i cant find it is a command to get all armors or how to find these ids

Comment: And yeah, EA is HIGHLY suspect...  All multiplayer tweaks are strongly recommended against.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ I don't know the answer. You could try posting it as a question (by hitting the "Ask Question" button at the top right of the page) to see if anyone else can help you.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to find more information and tips on tweaking the game and unlocking all weapons, armor. Is at masseffect wiki .. under guides there is a section for [Mass Effect 3 PC Tweaks](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_%28Mass_Effect_3%29). They have the information where to go and copy and paste the coding to unlock all weapons. Than you hit whatever key you bind it to and you get them all.

Under the section I also have guides to increase scanning radius, speed up the scanning on planets. Also to make the red circle on items you can pick up appear from further away, because in ME3 you have to be on top of an item to see the red circle and is easy to miss some weapons and armor on your first play through because of it.