# Can I change the Galactic Readiness in my game by editing the configuration?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is it possible to increase Galactic effectiveness in Mass Effect 3 by editing the coalesced.bin?  If it is, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Not directly, but you can in fact edit the value of earned resources to be worth 10k etc.

Grab the Coalesced.bin editor here - http://wenchy.net/me3-coalesced-utility/

bioui - sfxgame - sfxgawassetshandler - allassets

Pick something you haven't unlocked and go to the Type=GAWAssetType_Military items; set StartingStrength to a large number like 5000 or whatever.

All you really need is 10k, since 5k is the max needed and readiness can't dip below 50%. Just so you know, I haven't done this myself but know others have. I'm on the 360 and it's pretty trivial to get 5 to 6k.

Comment: Would you mind including some detail as to how to do this?

Comment: @ryansworld10 Check out [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54867/how-can-i-edit-coalesced-bin-so-that-i-can-use-cheats-and-graphics-tweaks) for additional details. Be warned, editing Coalesced.bin may expose you to a variety of reprisals from EA/Origin, and could interfere with your access to ME3 Multiplayer.

Comment: Thanks, I have been a loyal ME player since the start and I have never had to edit a game file to get the best results - however as I have a baby now, multiplayer is out for me (I need to be able to pause every time she cries), so I cannot increase readiness.

Comment: I can relate. You're going to be on pause a lot...

Comment: It's not going to be the end of the world for your team if you have to go AFK for a bit. It's not very nice, but nothing to exclude yourself from MP over.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your readiness to 100% by overwriting your local profile. This will reset your achievements. You will also need to manually load your save if you were in the middle of a game using "Load game" instead of "Resume", but after you've done that "Resume" will work as normal. [This archive](http://www.mediafire.com/download/4jjj1krk18hd8i2/Local_Profile.rar) ([alternate download](https://mega.co.nz/#!1o8DTDCK!FqfFMGf8tpKIj7dk2GpCEJs-xscLcDj0RJQ9KC-cXjY)) contains the file and instructions on where to place it.