# Can i edit the readiness rating without playing multiplayer in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the Galactic Readiness in my game by editing the configuration?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55171/can-i-change-the-galactic-readiness-in-my-game-by-editing-the-configuration)

I do not trust Origin one bit, I bought the game, but I don't trust Origin at all, so I only play games on it with offline mode and disabled internet (unplugged).

So I would like to either edit or find a way to up the readiness without multiplayer, I seriously don't want to play MP.

Comment: WHY do you distrust Origin so strongly?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes technically he's not specifically asking if he can edit the game configuration (right now) but that's probably his only option if he doesn't want to touch origin at all

Comment: So, when you run ME3, the Origin program doesn't run at all? If it does, I don't see how you're keeping it from scanning your files.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

Multiplayer and MEI (Mass effect infiltrator) are the only ways of increasing readiness.

Multiplayer will obviously require origin.

MEI uploads Intel (drops from dead enemies) to ME3 through origin, each 2 pieces of Intel giving 1% of galactic readiness.

Maybe you could connect to origin for a minute or 2 to upload Intel via MEI, this is the only way I can think of that doesnt require much online time.

Comment: without readiness going above 50% there is no way of getting te rating above 4k which is teh required amount for the "better" ending, which still sux lol.

Comment: Let's assume you play multiplayer once and get some level of readiness, then you go offline and continue single player only.  Will the game still report your level of readiness correctly?

Comment: @MatthewRead Most likely it will update your readiness straight away as you earn it.

Comment: @Havoc10K I have adjusted my answer by getting rid of the mistake plus i have added a solution which may apply to your case.

Comment: You will get theater of war offline and no updates, but i'm not planning to get ANY connection with Origin at all. I don't want them scanning my files, just because they claim they solved this problem I would like to know how you make a program that actually does it "accidentally".

Comment: My point is that if the value is shown while you're offline playing single player, then the value is stored locally and therefore can be edited.

Comment: @Havoc10K unless a save editor comes out there is no possible way of attaining readiness without origin. Shoulda got ME3 on xbox or ps3, no origin included :D

Comment: There is coalesced editor for ME3 out. also Thanks @SamuelStandrin gonna try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can play Mass Effect Infiltrator for iOS, and soon you'll be able to use the free iOS app Mass Effect Datapad, which has some minigames which increase your readiness.

Note that both of those tools use your Origin account and you'll have to be online for this all to work. Readiness is meant to work via Origin, there is no way around it without improperly tampering with game files.

I personally recommend the Multiplayer though, it's very fun and a fast way to build up readiness. Also not it is possible to get the best ending without increasing readiness, but you need to make near-perfect choices and complete pretty much everything possible in the game. A ME2 save import might even be required at that point, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: The Intel is uploaded via origin so that is a no go for Havoc, unless he follows the plan i suggested

Comment: @SamuelStandrin I know, but technically this does answer his question. It's without multiplayer and it's the only way to do this. It just *also* requires Origin.

Comment: This may be true but he doesnt want to connect to origin, AT ALL. which throws my plan to the wind :(