# Can I sabotage my war assets/readiness?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So I'm close to the end and I already have way too much Military Strength to get the worst ending. In fact, my readiness is over 90%, so I think I would have difficulty getting the worst ending even in a new game.

Is there some way I can lower my current Military Strength, either for a single character/career or by reducing my Readiness, or am I doomed to replay? I know Readiness decays naturally but it's much too slow.

I've already completed most sidequests (properly) so there's not much option to deliberately mess up quests unless it can be done retroactively.

Comment: There *may* be a way to do it via coalesced.bin if you pick up a war asset that you assign a negative value to. Or it might blow your game up. If you're feeling adventurous, try the reverse of what [they do here to increase it](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55171/can-i-change-the-galactic-readiness-in-my-game-by-editing-the-configuration).

Comment: PS3 version, editing coalesced.bin is a no go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. There's no way you can sabotage your war assets. There are a few war assets that can reduce, depending on your past actions (e.g. Rachni Workers / Alliance Engineer Corp.), but there's no way you can "bleed" or simply waste assets.

Comment: Boo. I kinda figured though. Guess I'll be ignoring all scanning and sidequests in my second playthrough.

Comment: Wrong! You can do that with [cheats](http://www.cheathappens.com/unlimitedonly.asp?chtid=31822) or editing the game files.