# Can not see the 3rd ending in ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have increased my EMS (Effective Military Strength) by Coalesced.bin editor and now it is about 11500 (reduced it to half cause my readiness is 50 percent, don't have time to play multiplayer) and I can also convince The Illusive Man to commit suicide, but nothing else has changed. I can not see the other ending, I have only 2 choices.

The strange thing is that the 1st time I finished the game (that time my EMS was near 6000), I had 3 options (all endings) but I chose to destroy The Reapers and after that whenever I have checked, only 2 options were available, even your solution did not work.

Comment: Did you try walking into the beam between the two other options? Did the Catalyst reference Synthesis, merging organic/synthetic life together?

Comment: At what point in the mission where you when you tweaked your Coalesced?  The EMS may be calculated for the end game when you start Priority:Earth and not calculated again.

Comment: @Ben : as I said, 1st time he suggest merging but I chose to destroy reapers. after that he never did it again (you know, I just believe that it was a bug or sth)

Comment: @ CaulynDarr : I changed my Coalesced during the mission in which u attacked cerberus base (only changed the value of reaper heart to 6000, the original was100) :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effective Military Strength is in fact LOCKED when you start the Cerberus Headquarters mission.  BEFORE Priority Earth.   This is the moment when you tell Hackett you're set and ready to attack. Simply editing a file and loading up your last save would not reset the locked value unless that save was made before the LOCK-IN action.

Edit the value and load an save before Cerberus Headquarters.

Comment: @ tiddy :what u'r saying really makes sense (I changed it during the mission in cerberus headquarter) I'll check it out, thanks dude.

Comment: *@*@*@*@* I'm Commander Shepard and I'm alive, so what Tiddy Said is 100 percent true, EMS is calculated before cerberus final mission. Thanks a thousand time pal ;). *@*@*@*@*

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you simply edited the save file leads me to believe that you simply chose an invalid value for that field.

To get the third ending, the EMS needs to be above 3000 (so your TMS needs to be above 6000).

The maximum TMS (and thus EMS) you can get is about 7800, so if you set your EMS to 11,500 I can see why that might have broken things. :) Try using a lower value instead.

Comment: @ Andrew : r u sure about what u saying, in this link it is said ''http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55171/can-i-change-the-galactic-readiness-in-my-game-by-editing-the-configuration/59480#59480'' that u need 5000 of EMS (as I checked the internet a lot of people suggested a number between 4000 to 5000). but thank you for your help, I'll check it later and let you know if it worked.

Comment: The 4000 EMS and 5000 EMS tiers can lead to a brief 2-second cutscene implying Shepard's survival, if you chose the Destruction option. Synthesis only requires 3000.

Comment: so do u think fixing my EMS to 10000 according to my readiness is good ?!!!(it becomes exactly 5000) or it's again too much.