# Editing and changing the crosshairs with coalesced.bin

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I have been playing a lot of multiplayer on *Mass Effect 3* and I have trouble seeing the light blue crosshairs when I am not zoomed in. Since aiming is difficult this way, I waste a lot of ammo shooting next to the monsters.

I know how to edit the coalesced.bin—my problem is I am not that familiar with doing it, where to look, or if this is even possible to change.

All I want to do is change the color of my crosshairs so I can see where I am aiming.

Comment: I was thinking this same thing earlier today.

Answer (score 1):

You risk getting banned if you use mods in multiplayer. Single-player mods are okay.

If you want to mod, you can only edit the *size* of the crosshairs, not the color. The details are [on the Mass Effect Wikia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_%28Mass_Effect_3%29#Properties_of_Individual_Weapons), but there is a great coalesced.bin tutorial [on this very site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54867/21177).

#### You have to tweak each weapon's crosshairs individually:

To select a weapon, go to **`bioweapon.ini/sfxgamecontent/sfxweapon`** and pick the weapon type and then individual weapon (e.g., sfxweapon => assultrifle => avenger).

> **CROSS-HAIR SIZE:**
>
> maxzoomcrosshairrange = (x= , Y= ) minzoomcrosshairrange = (x= , Y= )
>
> Cross-hairs DO NOT scale with accuracy. It is up to you to fix the cross hair size to fit the accuracy that you have modded.<sup>[1](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_%28Mass_Effect_3%29#Properties_of_Individual_Weapons)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of how to change the size but thats not going to help me aim with my M8. And yeah I am well aware of the whole banning thing, yet theres 110 people with higher N7 ranking than me (currently at 2109).

Comment: So you are assuming anybody who has a higher rank than you is a cheater?

Comment: No, but seeing I can get 20 levels a match, so 30 points in 14-20 minutes. And to stay in the top 10 for North America you need to get about 300 levels a day.

Answer (score 1):

Update: It appears that they have now written an advanced guide with a lot more information:
http://me3tweaks.blogspot.com/2013/01/mass-effect-3-advanced-multiplayer.html

I know this is old, but I was looking for some tutorials on Coalesced and found this post, and I figured when people came here to find info on it it would be useful if they found some.

I found a tutorial on a blog http://me3tweaks.blogspot.com/

Apparently whoever owns it likes using it in multiplayer, but the first post (bottommost) has a mini guide on enemies and stuff. It looks like it probably applies to single player too. 
It looks like they are making a mod manager too.
Also it doesn't seem like you can change the crosshair colors.