# Regenerate Full Health instead of Individual Bars in Mass Effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3

I felt quite nostalgic these days and wanted to run a full playthrough from ME1 to ME3, always on Insanity.

But then when I reached the last instalment I remembered how annoying is to always fight with only one bar of health because differently than ME2 we don't have a full health regen, only the most damaged energy bar.

I was looking for a way to tweak that behaviour only in ME3, after all, I've played several times in this 10 years timespan since the first title. It's possible, yes, but even a Husk kills you. >.<

Since usually these settings are configured in the *Coalesced.bin* I started there, but without much success.

I tried to change the entry `SFXGame.SFXModule_damageplayer\healthregenpct` (that's how ME3 Coalesced Utility shows to me) from **0.25f** to **1.0**, **1.0f** and **100**, repacking the file and restarting the game after each change, but the health doesn't regenerate as expected.

I didn't want to download one of those mega tweak packs form Nexus to not risk making my playthrough super-difficult (or super-easy). It's just this single píece of "immersion" if you call it that, that I don't really like.

Anything else I have to do?

Comment: what you are trying to do was not intended or explicitely allowed by the devs, so it has nothing to do here. Arqade is not meant to help in hacking games, in any way.

Comment: You could always just play on a lower difficulty level.  Especially if your goal is simple nostalgia - what are you trying to prove?  I mean, if it's *so important* that you play on Insanity all the time, then surely *any effort to modify the game* would ruin that goal.  After all, you're not **really** playing on Insanity anymore.

Comment: First, it's not a hack, it's a tweak, after all, I would like to do a minor modification for in my own copy on single-player mode. Second, if this kind of question is not supposed to be in here, topics like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54868/48020) wouldn't exist or be upvoted without being closed as it is. If you don't agree, fine, but don't come and tell me Arqade is not the place for such questions. @Steve-O, as the game balancing is not that great, lower difficulties too easy, hence the Insanity set-up.

Comment: I'm on the fence about this one. It seems to be asking about file modification, and I'm not a huge fan of that at all. But...its easily editable, and utilities have been made for that exact purpose, which we do help with. Hmm.

Comment: Yeah, but then again, without file modifications we wouldn't be able to play it in HD, for example.

Comment: If what @V4karian says is true. Then it is hacking. Devs don't allow it. So why should we?

Comment: @KevinTheGreat Because there a lot of things that the devs don't allow, but we as gamers have to do ourselves in order to get certain things working. I'm not even talking about this question in particular, but for example there are file modifications that are made to other games to that we can still play them on modern machines. This is just one example of why these types of questions are not a shut-and-close case.

Comment: all cases described here are irrelevant. This person is asking to intendly modify game files without devs consent. Bioware and EA are well known for not allowing people to modify their files: it is copyright infringement. Arqade is not meant for this. Calling it a "tweak" is a play on words, and you know it. Mentionning another question with such subjects is not an excuse: it just shows that no one's perfect, and that we have to watch ourselves more often. And it's not because a tool was made to hack software that it becomes legal to do so -_-

Comment: Extract from ME3's EULA : " Your right to use the Software is limited to the license grant above, and you may not otherwise copy, display, seek to disable, distribute, perform, publish, modify, create works from, or use the Software or any component of it, except as expressly authorized by EA."  Source : https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/eacom/en-us/eula/eula-mass-effect-3-en-10-5-11-final.pdf                   


Now tell me, what's your legal source for being authorized to modify such game files?

Comment: @V4karian We're not lawyers here.  We won't help with piracy, or online cheating, but modding for single player use isn't a big deal, I think.  Honestly, we're not the dev police.  We don't enforce their rights.

Comment: What a tempest in a teapot. Geez! Nevermind I asked, for god's sakes